# Laravel in production - Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I wrote an application in Laravel and i'm being tasked currently with deploying into production in a docker container. Everything has been going smooth so far, with 1 exception. The .env file. For security reasons, no containers can run under root, so they have to run under USER 1001 which only has read only access in shell - so I won't be able modify/generate,etc. Generally, I can use environment variables to insert it into an app that contains passwords, etc. It's also the "recommended" way of doing so. However, no matter what I try, Laravel looks for the .env file.

I created an empty .env file and tried to see if it can pick up the system env variables, but it hasn't worked. I modified config/app.php from `APP_KEY=env('APP_KEY)` to `APP_KEY=getenv('APP_KEY)` with no luck either.

I went into the .env file and added `APP_KEY=${APP_KEY}` also with no luck. I've also attempted to mount specifically the .env file from outside the container inside - the container crashes.

I've done a lot of research and I cannot seem to find a workable solution. Also, if the container restarts for any reason or a new push is made, that .env file will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a shell script entrypoint.sh to add values into .env base on container environment variables.

Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["command_to_start_laravel_app.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /app
# Setup defaults
TVAR=${API_NAME:=YourAppNameDefault}
TVAR=${API_ENV:=Production}
TVAR=${API_KEY:=none}
TVAR=${API_DEBUG:=false}

export API_NAME API_ENV API_KEY API_DEBUG
cat <<EOF>.env
APP_NAME=${API_NAME}
APP_ENV=${API_ENV}
APP_KEY=${API_KEY}
APP_DEBUG=${API_DEBUG}
APP_URL=${API_URL}

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
DB_USERNAME=${MYSQL_USER}
DB_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=${REDIS_HOST}
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=${SUBMISSION_HOST}
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=${API_MAILUSER}
MAIL_PASSWORD=${API_MAILPWD}
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=${API_ENCRYPT}

PUSHER_APP_ID=${API_PUSHER_APP_ID}
PUSHER_APP_KEY=${API_PUSHER_APP_KEY}
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=${API_PUSHER_APP_SECRET}
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=${API_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}

EOF
```